# WPF application sometimes(randomly) selects wrong value while printing

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I am not sure as how to put this up. Actually the code is right. 99% of the time, the print-out shows correct values but, now and then it prints some other value. If i again try to print the same page, the correct value is restored.

What can be the reason for this and how can i determine it for this error. Because whenever i try to run the application in VS on my development PC everything seems correct. Can this happen or has happened to someone else not just in WPF but windows or web application.

**EDIT**

After doing ~50 test entries, i was able to produce the error once and the noticeable thing i discovered following : (rather than writing code i am trying to explain in general)

```
A = 100
B = 9
C = A+B // but sometime C gets the value of 1000 treating B as 900
```

Actual code

```
VatOnAmount = ((decimal)record.Element("Amount") + 
                 (decimal)record.Element("Invoice").Element("CommissionAmount"))
```

Comment: I appreciate downvotes more than upvotes because they give you the idea that your problem is not real or vague or doesn't make sense. But, I hate it when someone does that without any explanation. Especially when the SO allows to comment under a question/post

Comment: Please explain your problem clearly, I didn't get it. By the way I am not the one who gave you the down vote :)

Comment: I have edited the question but will might open new question with more code and explanation if this isn't understandable still.

Comment: What do you mean by printing (Printer, Console, ...etc.)?

Comment: Printer A4 size....Actually i am reading from an XML file and then passing the datacontext to another .xaml page and then calling the print on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have an issue where you data binding / element values may not be updated at the time the property is called to get the value.  You may want to put some trace statements in your code to output values to see.  Also - do you get the same issues if you step through via the debugger?  Sometimes that changes race condition issues such as this.